# SecureSocial in play framework. Is that possible to use multiple logins in one account?

Tags: playframework, securesocial

SecureSocial in play framework.
Is that possible to use multiple logins in one account?
I have website which allow login to by Twitter, Facebook, Google+.
The same website allows load account’s data from any of those social media services.
Because of that I must make available login for example by Facebook to my page
and second login, to for example Twitter, to load account data.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible but you have to link those accounts in your application.

I´ve created a "User Profile" entity that has user information, such as name, e-mail, date of birth and other user information that the system requires.

Then I've created another entity "Profile Login", that is related 1-N with User Profile. That entity contains information of each login provider (user/pass, G+, FB...).

That make possible a User profile have multiples logins.

Inside the application I've created a "Link to another accounts" page, so the user can connect his account with other services.